# In keras, how to control the number of mini-batches drawn during one epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I read Keras's [official manual](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#what-do-sample-batch-and-epoch-mean) and a few examples such as [this one](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/). I understand that we can specify the size of a mini-batch using the `batch_size` parameter and specify the number of epochs using the `epochs` parameter.

But how can we decide how many mini-batches are there within one epoch? In `scikit-learn`, there are a few options to (indirectly) control this, such as `max_iter`, `tol`, etc. But I failed to find something similar in `Keras`

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221886/how-to-set-mini-batch-size-in-sgd-in-keras

Comment: I found this link before but it seems to me that it is **not** about the *number* of mini-batches but about the *size* of mini-batches. What I am asking is about the number of mini-batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way mini_batches are calculated in keras depends upon the size of your training data.

In the example that you have posted you can see that the **validation_split=0.2** that means It is Splitting the data into 2 parts i.e training and validation

**image_dataset_from_directory** is responsible for sending your data as mini_batches.

Total number of data points **23410**

training_data **18728 (80% of 23410)**

validation_data  **4682(20% of 23410)**

batch_size  **32**

therefore the number of steps or the number of minibatches that are calculated in the source code of **image_dataset_from_directory** is training_data/batch_size

steps_per_epoch is **585**  i.e there are 585 mini batches for that epoch which means 32 images are selected from the data 585 times

Comment: Thanks @keertika, I can see something like this when training a model: `Epoch 2/50
52/52 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.8672 - accuracy: 0.6362`, do you mean that `52/52` is a progress indicator about the number of mini-batches?

Comment: yes, you are right.